# hi am using Arduino Mega with LIDAR Lite V3 to create a map but it get restaring after some time

Tags: rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`

```
`#define USB_USBCON
   #define    LIDARLite_ADDRESS   0x62        
 #define    RegisterMeasure     0x00         
#define    MeasureValue        0x04        
#define    RegisterHighLowB    0x8f         
#include <ros.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LIDARLite.h>
#include <I2C.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Range.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.h>
#include <Timer.h>
LIDARLite myLidarLite;
#include <Servo.h>
float pos;
int i;
Servo myservo;
ros::NodeHandle  nh;
sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan;
ros::Publisher pub_range( "scan", &scan);
float ranges[100];
char frameid[] = "/base_link";
float lidarGetRange(void)
  {
int val = -1;
Wire.beginTransmission((int)LIDARLite_ADDRESS); // transmit to LIDAR-Lite
Wire.write((int)RegisterMeasure); // sets register pointer to  (0x00)  
Wire.write((int)MeasureValue); // sets register pointer to  (0x00)  
Wire.endTransmission(); // stop transmitting
delay(20); // Wait 20ms for transmit
Wire.beginTransmission((int)LIDARLite_ADDRESS); // transmit to LIDAR-Lite
Wire.write((int)RegisterHighLowB); // sets register pointer to (0x8f)
Wire.endTransmission(); // stop transmitting
delay(20); // Wait 20ms for transmit
Wire.requestFrom((int)LIDARLite_ADDRESS, 2); // request 2 bytes from LIDAR-Lite
 if(2 <= Wire.available()) // if two bytes were received
 {
val = Wire.read(); // receive high byte (overwrites previous reading)
val = val << 8; // shift high byte to be high 8 bits
val |= Wire.read(); // receive low byte as lower 8 bits
 }
  return val;
}
void setup()
{
nh.getHardware()->setBaud(74880);
Serial.begin(74880);
nh.initNode();
delay(1000);
nh.advertise(pub_range);
myLidarLite.begin(0, true);
myLidarLite.configure(0);
scan.header.stamp=nh.now();
scan.ranges_length=100;
scan.ranges= ranges;
myservo.attach(9);
 }
void loop()
 {
   for(i = 0,pos=0; i<100,pos<=180; i++,pos=pos+1.8)
   {
   scan.header.frame_id =  frameid;
   scan.angle_max= 3.14;
   scan.angle_min= 0; 
   scan.scan_time=0.0381;
   scan.angle_increment =0.0314; 
   scan.time_increment=0.039;
   scan.range_min = 0;  
   scan.range_max = 40000; 
   ranges[i] =lidarGetRange()/100;
   scan.ranges[i] =ranges[i];
   pub_range.publish(&scan);
   myservo.write(pos);
    }
  nh.spinOnce();
    }
```

Initially it works fine but after some time it shows error, Error is like

```
   [ERROR] [1510517471.428006]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

and while it restarting it also stops the servo

also tried various baud rates

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275674/hi-am-using-arduino-mega-with-lidar-lite-v3-to-create-a-map-but-it-get-restaring-after-some-time/) by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use some delays in your main loop. should help..

---

Originally posted by [AlirezaA2](https://answers.ros.org/users/33619/alirezaa2/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0